# Validating excel cell values with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

**EDITTED**

I want to do <strike>3</strike> 2 validations on a set of excel cells and if any of them fails, an error message should be displayed. 
I am able to successfully implement one of them. but i need help to incorporate the third one.

<strike>1. Check if the cell is left blank</strike>(I can catch the blank values by un-checking ignore blank)

2. Check if the cell has only text
3. Check if the length exceeds 3 characters.

<strike>AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C11:C1048576),ISTEXT(C11:C1048576), IF((LEN(C11:C1048576) > 3), FALSE, TRUE))</strike>

AND(ISTEXT(C11:C1048576), IF((LEN(C11:C1048576) > 3), FALSE, TRUE))

The length check is not working as expected. it wont allow me to enter even a text with 2 chars.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the NOT for all three arguments? I think your formula is missing a ")" if it is missing at the end, you need to reverse the false and true of the IF formula

Comment: @WyattShipman let me check

Comment: you were right. removed the blank check. still getting the same issue

Comment: The issue seems to be relative cell references in your formula.  If you click on different cells in the C11:C1048576 range, you'll find that they have different ranges in the validation window. The blanks inside those different ranges are causing the validation to fail. The first two answers here both avoid the shifting range issue that you have.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is:

```
= AND( ISTEXT( C11 ), LEN( C11 ) <= 3 )
```

that should be the data validation rule in cell C11. Now you can copy down or across.

Answer (score 0):

This will work too: `=AND(ISTEXT($C$11:$C$1048576), IF((LEN($C$11:$C$1048576) > 3), FALSE, TRUE))`

Comment: @NiH answered this first. I fixed a typo and my answer somehow moved up higher.

Comment: Answers are randomly ordered if they have the same score, I think.